# How to analytically continue a function across a branch cut

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, special-functions, branch-cuts

Assume we are given some function $f(z)$, which is analytic everywhere except for a branch cut along the positive real axis. I would like to know how to analytically continue this into the lower half plane. From what I've read, this is (in principle) somewhat straightforward. The analytical continuation of $f(z)$, denoted $f_\downarrow(z)$ is given by

\begin{equation}
f_\downarrow(z)
=
\begin{cases}
f(z) & \mathrm{Im}(z)>0,\\
f(z) + \rho(z) &\mathrm{Im}(z)<0,
\end{cases}
\end{equation},

where I define $\rho(z)$ as the analytical continuation of the function $\rho(x) = f(x+i\delta) - f(x-i\delta)$, which gives the discontinuity of $f(z)$ across the real axis. However, though I can calculate $\rho(x)$ for a given function, I don't know how to analytically construct $\rho(z)$ from $\rho(x)$.

Examples: If I take $f(z) = \sqrt{z-1}$, which has a branch cut for $z<1$ (taking the branch cut of $\sqrt{z}$ to be along the negative real axis), then we have $f(x\pm i \delta) = \pm i \sqrt{1-x}.$ This then gives $\rho(x) = 2i\sqrt{1-x}$. How do I take this $\rho(x)$ and find $\rho(z)$?

For this specific $f(z)$, it is simple enough to guess $f_\downarrow(z) = -\sqrt{z-1}$, since the minus sign will cancel the minus sign appearing in the square root for $\mathrm{Im}(z)<0$. In particular, $f_\downarrow(z)$ is continuous as one crosses the real line, and has the values $f_\downarrow(x>1)  = \sqrt{x-1}$ and $f_\downarrow(x<1) =i\sqrt{1-x}$. Note: see edit below!

However, I would like to be able to do this procedure in general.

Another example I have come across is $\arcsin(z)$, which has a branch cut for $\mathrm{Re}(z)>1$. Apparently, its analytic continuation across the cut is $\pi - \arcsin(z)$. I cannot obtain this result, although I can derive (I think) $\rho(x) = -i\ln(\frac{x-\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x+\sqrt{x^2-1}})$ for this function.

In particular, I am currently concerned with analytically continuing the complete elliptic integrals $E(z)$ and $K(z)$, and $\arcsin(z)$, across the $\mathrm{Re}(z)>1$ branch cut.

Thank you so much for your help!

**Edit**:
In my example with the square root, $f_\downarrow(z)$ is now continuous in the interval $(-\infty,1)$, but there is now a branch cut for $z>1$. This is totally fine with me. My hopefully better-posed question is, "Given some interval on the real axis, say $(a,b)$, I would like to construct a function $f_\downarrow(z)$ which is (i) equal to $f(z)$ in the upper half plane, and (ii), continuous as one crosses the interval $(a,b)$ into the lower half plane.

Comment: If you are given a function which is analytic everywhere except for a branch cut along the positive real axis, then your function is already given in the lower half plane, and there is nothing to do.

Comment: Hmm, I think I may be speaking too imprecisely. I would like a function which is equal to $f(z)$ in the upper half plane, but does not have a branch cut on the real axis. See my above example with $\sqrt{z-1}$, where the desired function would be $f_\downarrow(z) = \sqrt{z-1}$ for $\mathrm{Im}(z)>0$ and $f_\downarrow(z) = -\sqrt{z-1}$ for $\mathrm{Im}(z)<0$. Hopefully, this clarifies what I'm looking for!

Comment: The example in your comment has the whole real line as a branch cut, as you have not defined it at all for imaginary part of 4z$ equal to zero.

Comment: I'm taking the square root to have a branch cut along the negative real axis. With this convention, $f_\downarrow(z)$ is continuous as one crosses the real line, and has the values $f_\downarrow(x>1)  = \sqrt{x-1}$ and $f_\downarrow(x<1) =i\sqrt{1-x}$. Sorry again for not specifying this originally. In my experience, this is the standard branch that is used.

Comment: There is no such thing as a continuous function $f$ satisfying $(f(x))^2=x$ for all $x$.

Comment: You're right! Somehow this had slipped my mind. Indeed, in my example with the square root, $f_\downarrow(z)$ is now continuous in the interval $(-\infty,1)$, but there is now a branch cut for $z>1$. This is totally fine with me. My question is, "Given some interval on the real axis, say $(a,b)$, I would like to construct a function $f_\downarrow(z)$ which is (i) equal to $f(z)$ in the upper half plane, and (ii), continuous as one crosses the interval $(a,b)$ into the lower half plane. Hopefully, this formulation of my question is sufficiently well-posed. I've amended my post accordingly.

Comment: Such an analytic extension need not exist in general; for instance, your function might blow up everywhere along the branch cut.

Comment: That's a great point, which I didn't think about! Luckily, I am not concerned with such functions.

Comment: So, you want (for example) a function which equals $f(z)=\sqrt z$ in the upper half plane, and is continuous as you cross the interval $(-2,-1)$? Well, you can just move the branch cut; take the function $\sqrt z$ with the positive real line as the branch cut.